# "No valid predicate" error when upgraded from Meta_search to Ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ransack, meta-search

I've got an ActiveRecord model with a method defined like this:

```
def state   

  if deleted?
    :deleted    
  else
    :expired
  end

end
```

The 'search_method' is defined in the model as:

> search_method :state

In the view:

> = form.select :state, { :expired => 'Expired', :deleted => 'Deleted' }.invert, :include_blank => 'All'

With **Meta_search**, this method was working fine. But when I replaced the gem with **Ransack**, I get: **ArgumentError** in Sample Controller 
No valid predicate for state.

I'm following this behavior from meta_search search_methods, so I might be taking the wrong approach. Any one help me, please?

Comment: I think you need to apply the predicate to the field like `state_start`. Have a look at this issue https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

Ransack uses a predicate added on to the end of the field you're searching for to indicate how to search for it. If you have an attribute of `:state` on your model, you could search for states that match to 'expired' or 'deleted' using `form.select :state_match,` where the `_match` says to match records with state of whatever you selected. (Things like `_cont` (contains) or `_start` (starts with)).

Ransack makes SQL queries to find records, so if you had an attribute on your model like `:deleted_at` you could search by presence or lack-of. It won't look at methods, just the information stored in the db.

More predicates and info are here: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching